# Laravel error 8 Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, axios

Hi I have an API in laravel 8. I am trying to access 'localhost:8000/test' and I get error "Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException". I have the front in vue and I access axios.

Configuration axios in front 'utils/axios.js':

```
import axios from 'axios';

axios.defaults.baseURL = 'http://localhost:8000/';
axios.defaults.timeout = 18000;

export default axios;
```

Index.vue (from where the request is made):

```
import axios from '../utils/axios';

export default {
  name: 'PageIndex',
  methods: {
    test() {
      axios.get('test')
        .then(() => {
          console.log('ok');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
  },
};
```

File 'routes/api.php' from laravel:

```
<?php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('test', 'TestController@index');
```

I've tried both `Route::get('test', 'TestController@index');` and `Route::get('/test', 'TestController@index');` and it still doesn't work ...

I don't know what else to look at.

A greeting and thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing), the routes defined in the `routes/api.php` file are reachable by prepending `api` before the `URL`, therefore, the `axios.defaults.baseURL` should be `http://localhost:8000/api`.

Comment: Yes, this is the problem. Thank you so much :)